# How to install imagick for PHP 7 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, imagick, php-7

I'm trying to install Imagick extension for PHP 7 on Amazon Linux Server.

I typed the following command,

```
sudo yum install php70-php-pecl-imagick
```

and I get lots of error messages.

```
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libHalf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libImath.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libgvc.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libIex.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libcdt.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libgraph.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.9.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
       Requires: libIlmThread.so.6()(64bit)
```

I tried to 'yum install' those required libraries but it says no packages available, so I googled but no clues.

Anybody knows how to install imagick extension for php 7 or how can I install those required libraries?

Comment: What does `uname -a` output ?

Comment: Linux ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 17 22:45:04 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: what's your operating system ?

Comment: Here's what my /proc/version shows.

Linux version 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60007) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)

Comment: `sudo yum install libgtk2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0` see if the first error goes away

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: your `remi-save` repo should be for el7 and not for el6, what does  `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-safe.repo`  output ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri 
No package libgtk2.0-0 available.
No package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 available.

Comment: @PedroLobito [remi-safe]
name=Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/safe/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/safe/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to install imagick?

Answer (score 2):

**PHP 7.1X**

```
sudo yum install php71-pecl-imagick
```

**PHP 7.0X**

```
sudo yum install php70-pecl-imagick
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist remove the `remi-repo` for `el6` (which you don't use) and will cause serious troubles to your OS if you continue using it.

```
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-safe.repo
```

Then add the correct `remi-repo` for `el7`:

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm
```

Now try running `yum` again:

```
sudo yum install php70-php-pecl-imagick
```

Answer (score 1):

Running PHP 7.0 on Amazon Linux: This is the correct package name. You added an addition "-php-" in the name which wasn't valid.

```
$ sudo yum install php70-pecl-imagick
```